# minimum of functional

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ for $n \ge 3$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary and $a \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$
Let $$J(u)= \int_{\Omega}|\nabla{u}|^2 +\int_{\Omega}au^2-\frac{1}{p+1}\int_{\Omega}|u|^{p+1}$$ with $2 <p <2^*-1$, where $2^*= \frac{2n}{n-2}$
I want to show that this this functional is finite i.e well defined on $H^1_{0}(\Omega)$ and to compute $dJ$ The first two terms without the $a$ is the $H^1_{0}(\Omega)$ norm squared. The fact that
$a \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ makes these two terms finite. Is this the right idea? What about the third term?
I want to naively say that $$dJ=2(\int_{\Omega}|\nabla{u}| +\int_{\Omega}au-\int_{\Omega}|u|^{p})$$
How would I go about computing this derivative properly?

Comment: For finiteness: look into compact embeddings. The candidate for the derivative is not even wrong: start to think about the derivative of $x\mapsto |x|^p$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: what will that look like?

Comment: I see how the Sobolev embedding leads to  $u^{p+1} $ being in $L^1$ i.e the right most term is finite. Was my reasoning correct on the first two terms?