# minimum of functional for $u$ in $H^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, optimization

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ for $n \ge 3$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary.
Let $$I(u)= \int_{\Omega}|\nabla{u}|^2 +\int_{\Omega}u^2+\beta\int_{\Omega}|u|^p$$ with $\beta >0$, $2<p<2^*=\frac{2n}{n-2}$ and $u \in H^{1}_0(\Omega)$. Show that there exists a $u_0 \in H^{1}_0(\Omega)$ such that $I(u_0)=\min I(u)$  for $u \in H^{1}_0(\Omega)$.

I understand that this means that $u_0$ minimizes the functional but have not reached the sophistication required to prove this. I'd like to see why this is true.
Would the idea of using a minimizing sequence work? and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am gonna apply the direct method here. I will drop the $\beta>0$, as it is irrelevant in this context.
$\textbf{Step 1}:$ Lower bound
$$
I(u)=||u||_{H^1(\Omega)}^2+||u||_{L^p(\Omega)}^p \geq 0
$$
$\textbf{Step 2}:$Compactness
First of all, let us note that the Rellich embedding gives $u \in H^1(\Omega) \implies u \in L^p(\Omega)$. Your exponents match perfectly, as $p$ is smaller than the respective Sobolev conjugate.
Let $\{ u_k \} \subset H^1_0(\Omega)$ be a minizining sequence. Then we have
$$
||u||_{H^1(\Omega)}^2+||u||_{L^p(\Omega)}^p \leq C
$$
for some $C>0$. In particular, there exists a subsequence (not relabeled) which satsifies
$$
u_k \rightharpoonup u \; \textrm{ in } H^1(\Omega)   \\
u_k \to u \; \textrm{ in } L^p(\Omega)
$$
i.e. weakly in $H^1(\Omega)$ and strongly in $L^p(\Omega)$. The first one is simply a property of the Hilbert space you are working on - bounded sequences in Hilbert spaces have weakly convergent subsequences. The second one is again a consquence of the Rellich embedding, which is also compact in your setting. The fact that $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ follows from the fact that closed, convex sets are also weakly closed.
$\textbf{Step 3}:$ Conclusion
The $H^1(\Omega)$-norm (squared) is weakly lower semicontinuous and we have even strong $L^p(\Omega)$ convergence for our minimizing sequence. Therefore, we see that our functional is lower-semicontinuous w.r.t. to our sequence. We then conclude:
$$
\inf I(\cdot) \leq I(u) \leq \liminf I(u_k)=\inf I(\cdot)  \implies 
I(u)=\min I(\cdot)
$$
I hope this gives you an idea of what to do, there are still some details to fill in. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Why can't you replace all your $H^1$ by $H^1_0$ until right before step 3? Aren't the norms the same?Also what is a weakly closed set? Wikipedia tells me that a set is closed if it is closed with respect to the weak topology. Is a weakly convergent sequence a sequence converging wrt to the weak topology? if so how?

Comment: You could actually replace $H^1$ with $H^1_0$ earlier if you wanted to, but I usually deal with boundary conditions later.  A weakly convergent subsequence is convergent with respect to the weak topology. The weak convergence is simply a consequence of what I mentioned - the bounded Hilbert space norm of our minimizing sequence. If that does not answer your question, could you elaborate more please what exactly you don't understand?

Comment: I was just trying to understand what it meant to be weakly closed since this what you use to put deal with the boundary condition at the end. So the way I learned about weak convergence was basically something like a sequence of functions converges weakly to a function f if  $(f_n, \mu) \to (f,\mu)$ where $\mu$ is a linear functional. Topology was never mentioned. How does the weak topology fit in to this?

Comment: Could you chime in on this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4020075/minimum-of-functional

Comment: In order to get compactness for your minimizing sequence in the strong topology, you would have to put in considerably more effort. In other words: Finding a subsequence of the minimizing sequence converging in the "classical" $H^1_0$ topology induced by the norm is a lot harder than to just find a weakly converging sequence.   
Topology is, roughly speaking, "which sets are open in a space and which sequences converge". Understanding topology means understanding what convergence means.

Comment: For the other question you posted: Just use the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem. For computing the derivative $dJ$, I would recommend looking up what "derivative" in this context means - words like "directional derivate", "Gateaux derivative", "test functions" or "Euler-Lagrange equation" should, but do not have to, pop up in this context.

Comment: haven't found anything. The derivative of a linear function is itself so do the first two terms remain the same and the last one changes as expected?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not going to go more in-depth about your second question which you linked. I am sure someone else can post a full-detail answer for it.